# Express JS app does not recognize authorization token send by Angular

Tags: angularjs, express, http-headers, authorization

I am working on api, which runs as Express JS app, and I am using Angular JS to send requests to that api.

The api requires authorization send in header and I am struggling to do that in angular.

My Express JS code:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
// add details of what is allowed in HTTP request headers to the response headers
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '86400');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
// the next() function continues execution and will move onto the requested URL/URI
next();
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {

var header=req.headers['authorization']||'',        // get the header
    token=header.split(/\s+/).pop()||'',            // and the encoded auth token
    auth=new Buffer(token, 'base64').toString(),    // convert from base64
    parts=auth.split(/:/),                          // split on colon
    username=parts[0],
    password=parts[1];

r(header);
r(token);
r(auth);
r(username);
r(password);

if(username=='usr' && password=='pwd'){
    next();
}else{

    res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Birds.cz login"');
    res.status(401).send({error:'auth'});
  }
}
```

When I use `curl` to send this: `curl --user usr:pwd  http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/login`, the console prints:

```
Basic dXNyOnB3ZA==
dXNyOnB3ZA==
usr:pwd
usr
pwd
```

which is correnct.

My angular service looks like this:

```
function testLogin() {
  $http({
     method  :'GET',
     url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/login',
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert(data);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert('error');
        }).catch(function(error){
            alert('catch' + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
```

}

and in config of the whole angular app I have:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

//Enable cross domain calls
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';

// insert authorization header
var string = 'usr:pwd';
var encodedString = btoa(string);
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encodedString;

...
}
```

When I make request from Angular, the node js console prints five empty lines, therefore the Authorization header was not recognized at all.

Any ideas what is the problem?

**EDIT** When I use `Authorization` in http request header, the server returns error 0, but when I omit it, it returns error 401, as it should. It seems to me, that providing `Authorization` header breaks the code on server side before it sends the 401 error code.

**EDIT 2** When I log the request header in node js app, it does not show token `Authorization` at all

```
{ host: '127.0.0.1:8000',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0',
accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'accept-language': 'cs,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
origin: 'http://localhost',
'access-control-request-method': 'GET',
'access-control-request-headers': 'authorization',
connection: 'keep-alive' }
```

**EDIT 3** here is header of request, captured in firebug

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language cs,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Access-Control-Request-He...    authorization
Access-Control-Request-Me...    GET
Connection  keep-alive
Host    127.0.0.1:8000
Origin  http://localhost
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow requests to come from different domains, add this code at server side to tackle CORS related error -

```
var resolveCrossDomain = function(req, res,next) {

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.send(200);
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
}; 
    app.use(resolveCrossDomain);
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately that does not work, please see edited question

Comment: @Zbynek can you check the browser console, and paste a snapshot with what values are passing in

Comment: please see the edited question - the Authorization is not send

Comment: @Zbynek Can you please check that you are having `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`  at your server side ?

Comment: I do - `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    limit: '50mb'
}));`

Comment: I have noticed, that the method of the request is `OPTIONS`, not `GET`

Comment: @Zbynek Hey you have not added `Authorization` in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` please add, restart and clear cache and let me know then

Comment: Found the solution, it was caused by pre-flight OPTIONS request